# Playing a Transparent Video(H.264, AAC) on a Custom view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, transparent, gpuimage

I have a video which is transparent (H.264, AAC), there's an Imageview which is below the video view and it is playing animation of images. I want to play the transparent video on top of the image view . I tried using ***GPUImage Framework*** of ***Brad Larson***. I used ***ChromaKeyBlend*** filter to play the transparent video, but didn't got any success.

Searched through SO , got nothing about it.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var done: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: RenderView!
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "template", ofType:"mp4")
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    @IBOutlet weak var back: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagesPlayView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var templateImageView: UIImageView!

    var filter : ChromaKeyBlend!
    var movie:MovieInput!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imagesPlayView.animationImages = imageArray123
        self.imagesPlayView.animationDuration = 30.0
        self.imagesPlayView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        self.imagesPlayView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.imagesPlayView.startAnimating()

        videoPlayerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let videoURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)
        do
        {
      movie = try MovieInput(url:videoURL, playAtActualSpeed:true)
            filter = ChromaKeyBlend()
            movie --> filter --> videoPlayerView
            movie.runBenchmark = true
            movie.start()
        } catch
        {
            print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
        }


    }
```

App gets crashed. Crash log is :

Link log: ERROR: Input of fragment shader 'textureCoordinate2' not written by vertex shader

Shader deallocated --> ShaderProgram.swift: deinit: 62
ERROR: /Users/macmini/Downloads/GPUImage2-master/framework/Source/Operations/ChromaKeyBlend.swift

compilation failed with error: ShaderCompileError(compileLog: "Link error")
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. 
This may reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb)

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using GPUImage2 because there is no UIElement class available right now. Prefer link here:- https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/issues/17 But You can do using GPUImage(1). And here you are not passing second input(background image or video) that's why it's giving you an error. With GPUImage2 you can simply pass static image or video behind your transparent video. You can not pass animating imageView as UIElement.

---

Hack: If you want to create this using GPUImage2 first you have to make a video of you animating images and then pass that as a second input.

---

```
 do {
        movie = try MovieInput(url: videoURL, playAtActualSpeed: true)
        filter = ChromaKeyBlend()
        let backgroundImage = PictureInput(imageName: "backgroundImage.png") // <-- background image
        backgroundImage.processImage(synchronously: true)
        movie --> filter --> videoPlayerView
        backgroundImage --> filter
        movie.runBenchmark = true
        movie.start()
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
    }
```